# Python Class Correlation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I tried the question before. But maybe I have to keep it simple. I have a jaccard value which can go from 0 to 1. I have two categories, each going from 1 to 7. Each combination of these category values producing another jaccard value. Is there any method to find some kind of correlation between the category numbers and the jaccard value? So like value 1 of category 1 gives always a high jaccard with value 2 of category 2, or value 2 of category1 gives always a high jaccard, no matter what value of category 2?

```
import numpy as np
#[category 1, category 2, jaccard]    
array1 = np.array([[1,1,0.1627]
 [1,2,0.2993]
 [1,3,0.1192]
 [1,4,0.201 ]
 [1,5,0.0678]
 [1,6,0.2354]
 [1,7,0.1921]
 [2,1,0.1627]
 [2,2,0.2993]
 [2,3,0.1192]
 [2,4,0.201 ]
 [2,5,0.0678]
 [2,6,0.2354]
 [2,7,0.1921]
 [3,1,0.1627]
 [3,2,0.2993]
 [3,3,0.1192]
 [3,4,0.201 ]
 [3,5,0.0678]
 [3,6,0.2354]])
```

Comment: 'class', is that a Python Class, or just a name for your values?  As constructed your array will be `dtype` float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) is a great python package which includes tons of useful statistical/datascience functions, such as correlation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1,1,0.1627],
[1,2,0.2993],
[1,3,0.1192],
[1,4,0.201 ],
[1,5,0.0678],
[1,6,0.2354],
[1,7,0.1921],
[2,1,0.1627],
[2,2,0.2993],
[2,3,0.1192],
[2,4,0.201 ],
[2,5,0.0678],
[2,6,0.2354],
[2,7,0.1921],
[3,1,0.1627],
[3,2,0.2993],
[3,3,0.1192],
[3,4,0.201 ],
[3,5,0.0678],
[3,6,0.2354]])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["cat1", "cat2", "jaccard"], data=array1)
df.corr()
```

```
# correlation output
         cat1       cat2         jaccard
cat1     1.00000   -0.101380    -0.008720
cat2    -0.10138    1.000000    -0.109329
jacard  -0.00872   -0.109329     1.000000
```